# Android 2.3+ problems with RTSP playback

Tags: java, android

Currently I working on radio application for Android platform. Everything is working correctly but on Android 2.3+ I cannot play rtsp stream.

I've found that theres is a bug in Android 2.3+ with that: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13715

But I need to play this file. Is there any chance to make it work? Maybe it's possible to save some part of stream in temp file and pass this file to mediaplayer?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement / port gStreamer in JNI layer. And then control it via JNI.

You can find information about Android+gStreamer in Google.

I have edited this project https://github.com/spex66/RTSP-Camera-for-Android/
And fully implemented the rtsp client to work with remote servers.
You can find my code here http://www.4shared.com/rar/cm2e1ZML/RtspCamera.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Android 2.3 requires RTSP server to listen on default port - 554.